# Volume control affecting speaker balance rather than ouput on audio inteface

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

Ubuntu novice here so appologies for any silly questions. I haven't been able to find much on the issue so thought I would ask here.

I have set up an audio interface (Audient ID14) on my Ubuntu 22.04.02 machine but am having issues with volume control. When at max system volume the balance between the speakers sounds correct, however, when using the keyboard controls to reduce the volume, the left speaker's volume is not affected until the very last click, where the speaker then turns off. The right speaker reduces volume as expected linearly. This produces a panning type effect rather than volume reduction, hope that makes sense. I can currently change the volume correctly by keeping system volume at max and changing it directly on the audio interface, however, I would like to be able to control from my keyboard if at all possible so I can clear the interface from my desk and keep control/ have faster control.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what it could be or avenues to explore?

One thing I did notice is the on the PulseAudio volume control app it's saying that the ID14 is Analogue Surround 4 rather than stereo, could this be the root of the issue? I've tried fixing this with some if the searchable suggestions on here with no luck.

Thanks